# How to get the Iframes height in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

How can we get the height of a iframe using javascript from within the iframe in firefox.

I have tried using window.innerHeight, but is returning the total window height

I need the height of the iframe not its parent window

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the iframe by its id, using something like:

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').innerHeight()
```

Comment: How can we get the id of the Iframe from within the Iframe ?